# PHP trim row results?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm getting results in format

```
location1 2 4
location2 3 2
location3 0 0
location1 1 0
```

How can I trim results so that row returning 0 and 0 is not displayed ? thank you

.................

Here is Mysql query, I don't know how to trim it from MySQL so I thought using PHP ..

```
    SELECT hotelas.name, hotelas.address, hotelas.city, hotelas.country, hotelas.hotel_id 
AS hotelid, 
COUNT( DISTINCT apart.apartman_id ) AS number_of_free_ap, 
COUNT( DISTINCT room.apartman_id ) AS num_of_free_rooms
    FROM hotel AS hotelas
    LEFT JOIN apartman AS apart ON ( apart.apartman_hotel = hotelas.hotel_id
    AND apart.occupied =0
    AND apart.what =1 )
    LEFT JOIN apartman AS room ON ( room.apartman_hotel = hotelas.hotel_id
    AND room.occupied =0
    AND room.what =0 )
    GROUP BY hotelas.hotel_id
```

TABLE field what, 0 - for room, 1 - apartment

So I get a few columns among which the most important ones are count columns , free rooms and free apartments. So I have a test hotel which is full 0 rooms and 0 apartments and I want is removed from this list where all other hotels have at least one room or one apartment available.

Comment: You indicated that you didnt want to touch your SQL because it was too complex. If you post your SQL query, someone here might be able to help.

Comment: Its posted above, information about hotel are stored in a hotel table, information about rooms or apartment are stored inside apartman table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are querying you database to get this information and you can change the query, that would be the best place for it.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
    firstColumn != 0
OR
    secondColumn != 0
```

If you are getting this in PHP from some other source (CSV or something), or you don't have control over the query, use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
// i'm assuming each line in your example is an array of values
$myArray = array_filter($myArray, 'noDoubleZeroes');

function noDoubleZeroes($line) {
    return $line[1] != 0 || $line[2] != 0;
}
```

Comment: No, his SQL seems correct to me. The asker wants to remove results where BOTH columns are 0, so AND is the correct choise.

Comment: your solution works when I change your function to 

function noDoubleZeroes($line) {
    return $line[number_of_free_ap] != 0 || $line[num_of_free_rooms] != 0;
}

But I'm now getting empty results from column name, address, city, country

Comment: Ah, of course.  The SQL _excludes_, so it's an OR. Now I feel stupid.

Comment: @gnud - you and me both, buddy. @c0mrade, are you sure that your array's keys are what you think they are? try adding some echoes in the function to help debug: `print_r($line)` would help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where column1 !=0
or column2 !=0
```

That's how you can trim it in MySQL.

OTOH, if you have an array such as this ( you will usually get this after you query from a db)

```
array(array('location1', 2, 4), array('location2', 3, 2))
```

Then you need to loop over the array and do the manual filtering:

```
$newarrs=array();
foreach($arrs as $values)
{
  if($values[1]!=0 || $values[2]!=0)
    $newarrs[]=$values;
}
return $newarrs;
```

Comment: I have a pretty complex LEFT join query I don't know how to modify it. Its working so I should edit the results from PHP

Comment: You could post the query here. We might be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood you correctly this should help

```
$columns = explode($resultLine, " ");
$whatYouWant =  $columns[0];
```

Comment: You did not understand correctly. He wants to remove the rows with two 0's.